# Child class calls parent member instead of its own member

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to implement a couple of classes that share a lot of properties, by means of two classes that inherit certain members from a common parent class. In practice, what changes is how they handle a particular member, that would also be inherited, as it would be required from other members of the parent class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Parent{
public:
    Parent();
    Parent(const int _arg);
    ~Parent();
    int member1(const std::vector<float> _args);
    int member2(const std::vector<float> _args) { std::cout << shared(0.0) << std::endl;};
    int member3(const std::vector<float> _args);
    float shared(const float _val) {return 0.0;}; //dummy call in order for code to be compilable

protected:
    int protected_member1;
    int protected_member2;
    int protected_member3;
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
    Child1(const int _arg):Parent(_arg);
    ~Child1();
    float shared(const float _val) {return 2.1;};
}

class Child2 : public Parent {
public:
    Child2(const int _arg):Parent(_arg);
    ~Child2();
    float shared(const float _val) {return 1.7;};
}
```

In practice, `shared(const float _val)` does more complex and problem-specific stuff, I tried to simplify the code in order to illustrate the issue more clearly (and removed irrelevant parts of the code as the definition of the remaining class members). However, when I call `member2(const std::vector<float> _args)` from each of the child classes, what is called is the base class member `shared(const float _val)` and not the child member.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    Parent p;
    Child1 c1;
    Child2 c2;

    c1.member2(std::vector<float> (5,1.0));
    c2.member2(std::vector<float> (5,1.0));

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Would a different approach to the problem make more sense?

Comment: `shared` is not marked as `virtual`, so why do you expect it to participate in virtual-dispatch?

Answer (score 5):

Polymorphism is not switched on by default in C++ (unlike Java for example). You need to mark `shared` `virtual` in the base class:

```
virtual float shared(const float _val) {return 0.0;}
```

If you never require a base class implementation, then you can make it *pure virtual*:

```
virtual float shared(const float _val) = 0;
```

Finally, in child classes, you *can* mark the function `virtual` too, although that has no effect. From C++11 onwards you can use the `override` keyword to the function which can improve the robustness of your program as withdrawing `virtual` from the base class will cause a compilation failure:

```
float shared(const float _val) override {return 2.1;}
```

Comment: and if you want to have an implementation that must be selected explicitly then you can have pure virtual with implementation ... ohhhhhh ... I think I see why some people find C++ hard.

Comment: @UKMonkey: But it still remains the best general-purpose language out there by a country mile; in my opinion at least.

Comment: Don't disagree at all  :)

Comment: @UKMonkey: Most of the time, you still just follow a set of guidelines; just because you *can* implement a pure virtual function in C++ doesn't mean that such things often happen in real code. If you feel it's necessary to add an implementation to a pure virtual function, then perhaps you have gone too far with inheritance and virtual functions, and a `std::function` approach would be cleaner. People coming from Java or C# tend to overuse inheritance anyway.

Comment: Great answer. However, what would be the correct sintax for implementing this in separate header and cpp files? I'm getting linking errors just by adding `virtual` to the base class member.